# Constructors and prototype not appending results

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

Been coding for a few weeks now, i'm trying to write a simple pizza picker with  constructor and prototype.

I wrote 4 radio buttons with 4 different pizzas

Console log doesn't show any errors, but when it's time to order the price should appear on my results ID but it's not.

I'm guessing my prototype function is the reason why, but I wrote it very simply and I don't understand why it's not working.

Here is my JS

```
function Pizza(){
  this.type = [];
  this.price = [];
}

Pizza.prototype.newOrder = function() {
  if(this.type === 1){
    this.price + 5;
    return 
  }
  if(this.type === 2){
    this.price + 7;
    return
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var customer = new Pizza();
  $("button#order").click(function(event) {
  $("input:checkbox[name=pizza]:checked").each(function(event){
    customer.newOrder();
    $("#price").append(customer.price);
  });
});
})
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <title>ORDER PIZZA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class"container">
      <h1>ORDER PIZZA</h1>
      <form id="pizza-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>Pick a pizza</p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="1">Small1 <br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="2">small2<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="3">large1<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="4">large2<br>
        </div>
    </div>
      <button id="order" type="submit">ORDER</button>
    </form>
    <h2 id="price"> Total:  </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `this.type === 1`? Does `this.type === 2`?

What does `this.price + 5` do?

Comment: I would suggest reading more about [Constructors and prototypes](http://tobyho.com/2010/11/22/javascript-constructors-and/). Whenever you instantiate Pizza, type and price will always be empty arrays.

Comment: Learning how to debug _now_. It is the single most important thing to learn as a new coder. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: i found out this.price and this.type are declared as arrays, but I treat them as numbers.

Comment: What I meant was "this.price = this.price + 5;"

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with @jdv's comment above w.r.t learning some new debugging skills.

A few mistakes:

1. When you call `customer.newOrder`, within that function `this.type`'s value is still it's initial value of `[]` that you set in the constructor. You need to pass the selected value from the checkbox to the newOrder function as an argument. Note that the values of your checkboxes are of type String and not Number. Check the docs for [JQuery `each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
2. `this.price + 5` is not the correct way to increment the value of in Javascript. It should be `this.price = this.price + 5` or `this.price += 5` for short.
3. You need to reset the price to `0` every time to click on the button so it does not add the price to the previous order's price.

I am posting a probable solution to your problem, but this solution is worth nothing compared to having the skills to debug and read documentation, so I would encourage you to figure it out by yourself and not follow this solution -

```js
function Pizza(){
  this.type = '';
  this.price = 0;
}

Pizza.prototype.newOrder = function(pizzaType) {  
  this.type = pizzaType
  if (this.type === '1') {
    this.price = this.price + 5;
  }
  if (this.type === '2') {
    this.price = this.price + 7;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var customer = new Pizza();
  $("button#order").click(function(event) {
    customer.price = 0
    $("input:checkbox[name=pizza]:checked").each(function(index, checkbox){
      customer.newOrder(checkbox.value);
    });
    $("#price").html(customer.price);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ORDER PIZZA</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class"container">
      <h1>ORDER PIZZA</h1>
      <form id="pizza-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>Pick a pizza</p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="1">Small1 <br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="2">small2<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="3">large1<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="pizza" value="4">large2<br>
        </div>
      </form>
      <button id="order">ORDER</button>
      <h2 id="price"> Total:  </h2>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```